# Duplicate key in foreign table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these Oracle tables:

```
CREATE TABLE AGENT(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  GROUP_ID NUMBER(38,0),
  ........
)
/

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP_AG_GROUP ON AGENT (GROUP_ID)
/

ALTER TABLE AGENT ADD CONSTRAINT AGENTID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
/

CREATE TABLE AGENT_CONFIG(
  AGENT_CONFIG_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AGENT_ID INTEGER,
  .......
)
/

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP16 ON AGENT_CONFIG (AGENT_ID)
/

ALTER TABLE AGENT_CONFIG ADD CONSTRAINT KEY17 PRIMARY KEY (AGENT_CONFIG_ID)
/

ALTER TABLE AGENT_CONFIG ADD CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP16 FOREIGN KEY (AGENT_ID) REFERENCES AGENT (ID)
/
```

I want to use the first table AGENT as main table to store data. Into the second table I want to store configuration about AGENT and use AGENT ID as unique ID.

But I have this problem: I insert successfully row into table AGENT. I need to also add empty row with the same ID into table AGENT_CONFIG and later update that row. How I can duplicate this ID value duplication? Probably with Oracle table trigger? Is three any other way like special relation between the tables?

I use this SQL Query for insert into AGENT table:

```
INSERT INTO AGENT ("ID, GROUP_ID, NAME.....) VALUES (AGENT_SEQ.nextval, ?, ......)
```

Is this correct query:

```
INSERT INTO AGENT (ID, GROUP_ID......) VALUES (AGENT_SEQ.nextval, ?.......) 
RETURNING id INTO  INSERT INTO AGENT_CONFIG (AGENT_SEQ.nextval, Agent_ID) VALUES (id)"
```

Comment: I removed the Oracle version tags because you had multiple versions, which is not helpful.  Feel free to re-add the one with the version that matches your database.

Comment: surely there is information by searching the web which will give you a start.  whether you do it in a trigger or whereever you are looking to recieve the IDs of inserted rows so that you can then insert those into another table.  So look up how to return identity column after insert.  In sql-server I would use the OUTPUT inserted table I am not sure the equivalent in oracle

Comment: There are at least two ways. 1. [returning into](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2122356) clause of the `insert` statement. 2. Selecting `currval` values of a sequence (assuming you use sequences to generate primary key(`ID`) values ).

Comment: Can you show me the first one please?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Comment: Is this correct SQL query?     `INSERT INTO AGENT (ID, GROUP_ID......) VALUES (AGENT_SEQ.nextval, ?.......) 
    RETURNING id INTO  INSERT INTO AGENT_CONFIG (AGENT_SEQ.nextval, Agent_ID) VALUES (id)"`

Comment: So you want to have exactly one record for each ID in both tables, a real 1:1 relation? Is there any good reason not to use one single table instead?

Comment: I want to split them because later I want to have different configurations. Can you show me how I can implement this?

Comment: What means "different configurations"? Two or more configs per agent?

Answer (score 0):

For this use currval pseudocolumn (as @Nicholas Krasnov specified) of the sequence that you are using after you use nextval for table "AGENT". Currval will duplicate the value that you used for table "AGENT".

So for example :

```
1. INSERT INTO AGENT (ID, GROUP_ID......) VALUES (AGENT_SEQ.nextval, .......) 
2. INSERT INTO AGENT_CONFIG (AGENT_CONFIG_ID,AGENT_ID) VALUES (NULL,AGENT_SEQ.CURRVAL) ;
```

Link for Sequence Pseudocolumns --> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns002.htm

Answer (score 0):

To establish a 1:1 or 1:{1,n} relation is not that easy:

- On every insert in the parent table you'd have to make sure an according insert in the child table is also made.
- On every delete from the parent table you'd have to make sure to delete the according child records (usually via cascading delete or by mere foreign key constraints).
- On every delete from the child table you'd have to make sure it's not the last one for its parent. (And in that case either forbid the delete or delete the parent with it.)
- Forbid or react on updates to the IDs.

You can solve this by disabling (i.e. not granting) direct inserts and deletes (and maybe updates) on the table and provide PL/SQL functions to handle these instead.

If you are okay, however, with a 1:{0,1} or 1:{0,n} relation, then you can simply write the parent record and then look up its ID to write the child record(s).